# C++ Builder XE and JEDI JCL

Tags: c++builder, jedi, c++builder-xe, jedi-code-library

Has anybody successfully compiled the JCL for C++ Builder XE?  I have tried on XP and Win7 with no luck.  I have [filed a bug](http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5331) but this is a show stopper for me right now, so though I would ask here.  I am using the latest release from sourceforge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://forums.codegear.com/thread.jspa?threadID=42705

Still didn't totally fix it for me; I guess they still have some issues to resolve.

Comment: JCL does not currently compile out of the box. I have file a bug: http://issuetracker.delphi-jedi.org/view.php?id=5331